# Creating DOM objects using plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, raphael

In Raphael each and every thing you draw is considered as a DOM element, so you can directly call events on them.How can i implement the same thing if i use raw/plain JavaScript and not use any of the JavaScript libraries?

Comment: You can start with [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)

Comment: Please see the body of my question.My query is how could i interact with the canvas drawings so that i could call events directly on them in the way it could be done using Raphael JS

Comment: Here you go [EventTarget.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: Can you please send me an example of calling a simple click event on a rectangle drawn using plain JavaScript using the function you just mentioned?